# User movement direction from BlackBerry app

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

How do I get the direction the user is facing or the direction the user is traveling in a BlackBerry java application?

Comment: direction information ?? explain bit more

Comment: north , south directions or direction user is facing or direction user is traveling?

Answer (score 3):

The [getCourse()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/location/Location.html#getCourse%28%29) method in Location will give you the degrees relative to true north.  E.G

```
LocationProvider provider = LocationProvider.getInstance(null);
Location loc = provider.getLocation(-1);
float dir = loc.getCourse();
```